# Wget error bash Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, wget, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm getting an error in WSL while trying to download using wget

```
 wget -O quotefile.txt "https://www.google.com"
```

Output

```
Will not apply HSTS. The HSTS database must be a regular and non-world-writable file.
ERROR: could not open HSTS store at '/home/atul/.wget-hsts'. HSTS will be disabled.
--2020-04-08 12:47:43--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 2404:6800:4002:80f::2004, 172.217.166.196
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2404:6800:4002:80f::2004|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘quotefile.txt’

quotefile.txt                     [ <=>                                              ]  14.68K  --.-KB/s    in 0.002s

2020-04-08 12:47:45 (6.43 MB/s) - ‘quotefile.txt’ saved [15029]
```

Why i am getting this error

> ```
> Will not apply HSTS. The HSTS database must be a regular and non-world-writable file.
> ERROR: could not open HSTS store at '/home/atul/.wget-hsts'. HSTS will be disabled.
> ```

and how to solve this ?

I am facing this problem after fresh reinstall.Earlier I was using Windows 10 Pro Version 19035
but right now i am using Windows 10 Pro Version 1909.

Comment: Do you mean 1903? HSTS is a security feature designed to insure website domains go to their proper location.  You must configure wget to work with a secure connection.  Try **--no-check-certificate**

Comment: @Ramhound --no-check-certificates disables tls cert check completely which is dangerous and not necessary as you can just disable hsts using `--no-hsts`

Comment: @Robert - Sounds like you should answer the question.  I only suggested a possible solution as I wasn’t sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HSTS is an optional security measurement on top on HTTPS. As the HTTPS connection itself works and the file has been downloaded this seems to be rather a warning than an error. Therefore I see three options:

1. Disable HSTS on each call using the wget option `--no-hsts`
2. Try to create a file in `/home/atul/.wget-hsts` with the appropriate permissions and try if wget makes use of this file
3. Just ignore this warning

Answer (score 7):

I just came across the issue myself and in my case the `.wget-hsts` file was group and world writeable. I've just limited it to be user writable and the error vanished:

**Before**

```
-rw-rw-rw-  1 matthias matthias  165 Mar 13 13:57 .wget-hsts
```

**After**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 matthias matthias  165 Mar 13 13:57 .wget-hsts
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. For reference, running `chmod 644 .wget-hsts` will do the job of setting the file to user writable.